# Multiplication of inverse probabilities to get mean runtimes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

In a textbook I'm reading, there's an example about the average number of picks one would have to make from a set $X$, to get a first and second item from a set $|Y|\subseteq|X|$ that satisfies a property and isn't the same i.e. $y, y' \in Y: y\neq y'$. (It's assumed that |Y|>1).

Say, the set is size |X| and the amount of elements satisfying the property is |Y|.

I get that the probability for selecting the first item $y$ is $\frac{|Y|}{|X|}$, and the second is $\frac{|Y|-1}{|X|}$, since we can pick from the entire set (including $y$), but $y$ is removed from "the items we want", i.e. $|Y|-1 = Y\backslash\{y\}$. However when they combine them to form the mean, they use
$$ \frac{|Y|}{|X|} \cdot \frac{|X|}{|Y|-1}, $$
and I'm curious as to why the second probability is flipped? I can't seem to make sense of it.

In "marble examples" [online](http://www.ultimatemaths.com/finding-probability-of-single-or-combined-events.htm) they draw graphs, which I've done as sanity checks to get the first probabilities, but then they add them together. I'm unsure about what's used here, specifically what the probability, 
$$\frac{|X|}{|Y|-1},$$ is modeling.

[Edit 1, "solution"]: We only continue picking the second item, if the first item $\in |Y|$.
$$\frac{|X|}{|Y|-1},$$ is not a probability, it's the mean number of times we'll have to pick from |X| to get an item from $Y\backslash\{y\}$. Multiply this with the probability that we pick the first item, to get the mean.

Sometimes we'll terminate after picking the first element, sometimes we'll continue, given $Pr[y \in Y].$ When we continue the mean is $\frac{|X|}{|Y|-1}$, so the combined mean becomes
$$ \frac{|Y|}{|X|} \cdot \frac{|X|}{|Y|-1}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chance for the second item should be $\frac {|Y|-1}{|X|}$ because, as you say, there is one less of the type.  They are computing the mean number of times you would have to pick a pair to get two with the property.  For one item, the mean number of times to pick is $\frac {|X|}{|Y|}$, the inverse of the probability.  For two, it should be $\frac {|X|}{|Y|} \cdot \frac {|X|}{|Y|-1}$.

Added:  The quantities $\frac {|X|}{|Y|}$ and $ \frac {|X|}{|Y|-1}$ are not probabilities, they are greater than $1$.  They are mean waiting times for the events to occur, which are the inverses of the corresponding probabilities.

Comment: It's not $|X|-1$ since you're allowed to pick the first element again, it's just not a "good" element anymore since it's picked. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Then the first probability should be flipped, too, when computing the mean number of trials to get two items you want.

Comment: So $\frac{|Y|}{|X|} \cdot \frac{|X|}{|Y|-1}$ is actually the proability that the first have already happened, times the mean time for the second event? I might've asked the wrong question then. Because they actually assume that they've already picked one "good" element, and it's the mean, for getting the second.

Comment: It is, but I don't know why you would compute that.  If you want the mean number of trials to get a good second item where you know you picked a good item first it would just be $\frac {|X|}{|Y|-1}$

Comment: I have asked multitudes of "almost correct" questions, I'll edit it and answer it, thanks for all the help, now I understand what's going on.